# can't find referenced method 'void setPluginsEnabled(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I'm attempting to compile my application using Proguard and Eclipse and I'm getting the following errors:

```
Warning: com.adsdk.sdk.mraid.AdView: can't find referenced method 'void setPluginsEnabled(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
Warning: com.adsdk.sdk.video.WebFrame: can't find referenced method 'void setPluginsEnabled(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
```

It seems that these classes were [depreciated in 4.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes/android.webkit.WebSettings.html) and a [similar post in another random forum](http://ec2-50-18-152-10.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/questions/760/using-proguard-with-android-sdk-51) suggests that the solution is to change the target back to 17 and compile against 4.2.

Surely this isn't the only solution....?

I've tried adding the relevant removal of warnings code and keep class members etc to the Proguard config file, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I don't use these classes directly in my code - They are referenced from the Admob SDK Jar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turned out to be a pretty simple fix for me. You need to add the following into your Proguard config file:

```
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
```

I had previously included:

```
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebSettings.**
```

But that was wrong due to it being a Method, rather than a Class I believe.

Hope this helps someone who may be stuck like I was.

Comment: You can also use `-dontwarn android.webkit.WebSettings` to more accurately ignore only warnings that come from the Class `Websettings` and not all the Classes in the package `android.webkit.` which is what your first option filters out. The reason the 2nd option didn't work is because you were trying to filter Classes within the package `android.webkit.WebSettings.`, which of course is a Class and not a package. And for anyone wondering, if you want to filter an innerclass the syntax is `Websettings$Innerclass`. The Proguard docs are definitely difficult to decipher.